# change size of Scroll Viewer UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a `Xaml`

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
 <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/porsche.jpg"
   Tapped="UIElement_OnTapped"
   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
 </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

And C# code

```
private void UIElement_OnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var ct = (CompositeTransform) (sender as Image).RenderTransform;
    ct.Rotation += 90;
}
```

The problem is that after turning on the pictures (not square) Scroller is old and `HorizontalOffset`and  `VerticalOffset` and they do not have a setter. How I can update the `ScrollViewer` for new aspect ratio?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue as [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36245815/vertical-text-in-uwp-apps-with-xaml) posted today. The [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36248667/628821) provides a comprehensive mechanism for handling this requirement.

Comment: Do you know how to use it if I want change rotation angle while program running in C# code. `Binding` doesnt work and directly change Angle doesnt work