# Why is Textblock not maximized

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Have a simple Page with a grid and three columns. On the left and right side would a vertical text is needed.  Why is the text in Textblock not autoscaled and maximized to available space in viewbox?. This happens only when I rotate.

```
<Grid Background="White">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" >
        <TextBlock Text="ABC"  
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   TextAlignment="Center"
                   Foreground="Red"
                   Padding="0" Margin="0"
                   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>
    </Viewbox>

    <Canvas Grid.Column="1" Background="DarkBlue"/>

    <Viewbox Grid.Column="2">
        <TextBlock Text="ABC abc ABC abc"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   TextAlignment="Center"
                   Foreground="Red"
                   Padding="0" Margin="0"
                   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">

            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>
    </Viewbox>

</Grid>
```

What I´m doing wrong?

Comment: I have tested your code, the viewbox still stretches well when the textblock does not rotate. You could remove the Viewbox to check whether the UI of textblock is different. If you want to make the effect clearer, you could set the width of the second column to *.

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT  I need the viewbox to autoscale the textblock. How can I perform this without a viewbox.

Comment: What I mean is that the scaling effect may not be obvious, so you think that it hasn’t been scaled. Therefore, I suggest you could remove the Viewbox to check whether the UI of the textblock is different.

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT: I got it now. I changed from <TextBlock.RenderTransform> to <TextBlock.LayoutTransform> and now it works like supposed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I tried <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>, but this is not avail for UWP. But I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36245815/vertical-text-in-uwp-apps-with-xaml)